# Fatal error: Call to a member function getLoginUrl() on a non-object

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-sdk-3.0

I want to integrate facebook in my website and want to just verify if Facebook is configured properly but when I use `$this->facebook->getLoginUrl()` it gives:

```
"Message: Undefined property: Fblog::$facebook"
```

and is also showing

```
"Fatal error: Call to a member function getLoginUrl() on a non-object"
```

My code is:

```
class Fblog extends CI_Controller {
    public function __constract(){
    parent:: __constract();
    $this->load->library("facebook",array(
        "appId"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "secret"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ));
    }
    public function index(){
        echo $this->facebook->getLoginUrl();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try this out of your class?

Comment: yap but same problem

Comment: so I think you should clarify your question, art of asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the Facebook library is installed in the framework. Check these similar questions for [php extension missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107959/facebook-php-sdk-not-loading-as-a-library-in-codeigniter) and [correct config structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470194/facebook-php-sdk-codeigniter-unable-to-load-config)

Comment: thanks @thanedar Actually now If I try to autoload the facebook library, then its working but it gives a "Message: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent" .... so can you suggest me please

Comment: @dsdeveloper: If you don’t know what that error message means, then _please_ go research it.